# How to find if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) is FALSE

Tags: php, isset

I am using the $_SESSION global variable on each page on my application so that I can control access to my site with login functionality. Instead of using the following path that searches for TRUE else FALSE, as showed in the example below, how can you reverse the condition?

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
} else {
    echo "You are not logged in!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean `!isset()`? If you add a `!` to the beginning of your `if` statement, it turn it around.

Comment: Take a look at [**logical operators in PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), specifically the `not` operator. This is more or less universal for all programming languages, though.

Comment: Thank you. What I really want to do is if display my site page only if the user has an active session. I have the login functionality working, but now that I try to insert this piece of code on every page, I can't get it to work. Maybe that is the subject of another topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [**logical operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in the PHP manual, your problem is solved and explained *very well* there. So please, take a look.

---

### In this case

If you want to turn your `if` statement around, you should do this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo "You are not logged in!";
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
}
?>
```

*Simply put:* `!` means *not*.

In this particular case, you are using the `!` operator, which means that you are turning around your `if` statement normally goes through if it's **true**. So, if it's `isset()` but you add the `!` operator, you check if it's `notisset()`, in a way,  where the *"not"* is a `!`.

---

### The manual

The manual puts it like this: `if(!$a){}` is **true** if `$a` is **not true**.

Comment: Although I know what "this" is, you should add some text, preferably with references, and a description what this change means and why its significant; it might not be obvious to future readers.

Comment: @Qirel - I edited my original post to help future readers. I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this? You just have to negate isset with !, so you're essentially saying IF NOT / ELSE instead of IF / ELSE

```
 <?php
 if ( !isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
      echo "You are not logged in!";
 } else {
      echo $_SESSION['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An exclamation sign  `!` equals "not", like

```
if (!isset(...etc...
```